# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] vs $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Tags: php, variables

Is there a difference in performance in these two different ways of including an external script?

Without using a variable:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/class/conf.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/class/Db.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/class/Posts.php';
```

Using a variable:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include $path.'/class/conf.php';
include $path.'/class/Db.php';
include $path.'/class/Posts.php';
```

I avoid variables the more i can for memory purposes but i dont know if this is a good practice for performance or not.

Comment: is a single variable going to hurt performance that much to think of optimization? isn't better readability more important here?

Answer (score 7):

*I  avoid variables the more i can for memory purposes*

This is what's called "premature optimization".  Unless you know specifically that you have a memory problem, and that your assigning of a string that is maybe a few dozen characters long to it is adding to your memory problems, then don't try to save space.

*Is there a difference in performance*

Same goes for worrying about "performance".  The amount of time difference between the two approaches is so small as to be meaningless, and certainly imperceptible, especially when it is only done once per script.  Also, the amount of time different between the two ways of creating the string is insignificant compared to the time that it takes to hit the disk to load the PHP and parse it.

Far better to concern yourself with [the DRY principle](http://www.artima.com/intv/dry.html): **Don't Repeat Yourself**.  DRY helps you prevent problems like this:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/class/conf.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMEMT_ROOT'].'/class/Db.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/class/Posts.php';
```

"None of my database functions work!  What's wrong?"

Comment: I would prefer using `__FILES__` instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to include files. Think of a scenario if the application is not installed in the document root.

Comment: I understand your way of thinking and the concept of "premature optimization". On the other hand, by having in mind to avoid variables wherever there is another way to achive the same thing or to use functions/classes instead of "coding in the global scope", it is just a way of thinking and, i think that it doesn't increase the development time when it becomes 'the natural way of coding' for someone. The same applies client side by avoiding the constant use of divs (divitis) or by avoiding the use of a class where you can use an id. ...

Comment: ... Also, i don't really agree with the way of seing a variable as 'just one variable'. 'One variable x webpage's users' is more realistic. But here it comes the premature optimization : ) As a not so mature developer, i am trying to find a balance between proper coding and premature optimization. I would like to read your thoughts on what i wrote in this comment. Thank you for your help : )

Answer (score 4):

> I avoid variables the more i can for memory purposes but i dont know
>   if this is a good practice for performance or not.

This is definitely not good practice. One variable is actually nothing for current processors.

Go for **readability** and **maintainability**!

In addition, a variable adds a layer of indirection, i.e. you can simply modify `$path` if you want to change your paths. Modifying `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not a good idea.

I would also advise you to create a constant instead of a variable:

```
define('CLASS_DIR', 'your value');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class folder is located in the same place where you declare the inclusions.

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__).'/class/';
```

Then autoload your class from that folder.

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include $path . $class . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```